# How to upload an image in iPhone application

Tags: iphone

I want to create an application where I want to upload image from the iPhone in my application.

For example, in the contacts directory application, You have an image icon for each of the user and when you click on the icon, it takes you to the picture gallery to upload the photo for that person.

I want to implement the same thing. How to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Just asking but are you saying that you want to use picture from your iPhoto library in your app. Like the address book functionality?

Or upload pictures from your library to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to save the image you will need to use he uiimagepicoercontroller class to take a picture from camera or get it from phto album, then u will need to use the mehod UIImageJpEgRepresentation(image,int) to get the images data, then u can persist the image data by using core data or writting it to a file

Comment: do you know any tutorial or any kind of application doing that. It will be a great help to me. tnx.

Comment: hmmm, the project PhotoLocations might hasve an example on how t o use UIImagePickerController (its very straight forward), i dont have the source infront of m e so i cant be sure...

Answer (score 1):

Check out this useful tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQXaJO36I7Y&feature=player_embedded

Source code is available in the description.